# Django: how to get a fresh connection to the database

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have built a web server with django.

And use a thread to run task, which save data sent from clients to the database.

> ```
>   while True:
>       ...
>       try:  
>           self.dbTarget, created = ClientMonitor.objects.get_or_create(Machine_code=own_MachC)
>
>           data = self.workQueue.get()  #from client sent
>
>           self.dbTarget.setValue(data) #Custom method assigning
>           self.dbTarget.save()         #django ORM
>       except InterfaceError as ee:
>           pass
> ```

The thread is long-running, but it will except a InterfaceError after a long time because the mysql server disconnect as eight-hours timeout.

> Especially it can not auto-reconnect to the db. Creating a new thread will be OK, but it will increase resource occupation.

So I want to reconnect db when connection closed in the same thread. Also Django each request gets a fresh connection.

How I can get a fresh connection to the database in the same thread?
Thank you!!!

Comment: I can call   `connection.connection.close()` to simulate the 'InterfaceError ' .But this may be different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just close the connection in your exception handler. A new connection should be established the next time that your application attempts to communicate with the database:

```
import logging
from django.db import connection

try:  
    self.dbTarget, created = ClientMonitor.objects.get_or_create(Machine_code=own_MachC)
    ...
except InterfaceError as ee:
    logging.warning(ee)    # make sure that you log these events
    connection.close()
```

Comment: If I call 'connection.connection.close()' to simulate the 'InterfaceError ' and then  `connection.close()` will relive the connection.

Comment: Great! It work. I change mysql-server's wait_timeout from 8 hours to 3 second. And It will reconnect like above my edit.

Answer (score 5):

Django itself uses the function [`close_old_connections()`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/__init__.py#L59) to close any connections past their lifetime at the start and end of every request. This detects whether the connection is older than the `MAX_AGE` specified in your database settings, or is otherwise unusable. If you set your `MAX_AGE` lower than the database's timeout, you should never encounter an `InterfaceError` due to a db timeout.

```
from django.db import close_old_connections

while True:
    try:  
        ...
    finally:
        close_old_connections()
```

Comment: I don't set CONN_MAX_AGE paramete, so the default value is 0. I can not test whether 'close_old_connections()'  OK or not ,because it spent 8-hours to except the InterfaceError .

Comment: If I call 'connection.connection.close()' to simulate the 'InterfaceError ' and then 'close_old_connections()' will except 'django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: closing a closed connection'.

Comment: @Mix Of course, a connection that is timed out on the server side is not the same as a connection that is explicitly closed from the client side, and they produce different errors. Server timeouts should be handled by `close_old_connections()`.